# Syntax error unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting the following error `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`  on this line `$this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName 'User Registration Confirmation');` have I make a mistake with the `'' and ""`?  I have also past the name as $data can I include this in the subject instead of the model call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably forgot a comma: Try this:

```
$this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName, 'User Registration Confirmation');
```

instead of

```
$this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName 'User Registration Confirmation');
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a dot.

```
$this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName.'User Registration Confirmation');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss to concatenate the two strings (coreCompanyName and "User Registration Confirmation)? Write a "." between the two. See also [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

The code should look like:

```
$this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName . ' User Registration Confirmation');
```

Comment: no, he's just missing a comma, not a dot

Comment: The subject method doesn't seem to have two parameters... see [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)